# Need help scaling creating views of a diagram

Tags: modeling, image

I'm working on a model of a steam locomotive and I don't know how to scale the diagram to be the correct size as well as create front and back views of the locomotive. the length of the locomotive from end to end is 48ft 6 7/8in long, I tried making the drawing larger and measuring it until it said something around 48.785' but it didn't seem to work to well. also is there a way to lock the diagrams so when I am creating the model I don't shift them? if anybody could help that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the diagram ur drawing doesn't become larger then you can duplicate one coach by pressing (Ctrl+D) and put it in the back of coaches and do this till you get the size you want..
And if u want to add words on the engine it can be done by UV unwrapping..
Hope it will help.
I'm also new to Blender btw!Thank you.